# Count and group by issue

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have that table :

forum:

```
 _____________________________________________________________
|match_static_id| comment   | timpstamp            | user_id  |
|_______________|___________|______________________|__________|
|  1            |  Hi       | 2013-07-10 12:15:03  |     2    |
|  1            |  Hello    | 2013-07-09 12:14:44  |     1    | 
|_______________|___________|______________________|__________|
```

the working query is:

```
select forum.match_static_id, 
       count(forum.match_static_id) 'comment_no' 
Group By forum.match_static_id
```

But what if I want to have:

```
select forum.match_static_id, 
   count(forum.match_static_id) 'comment_no',
   forum.timestamp
Group By forum.match_static_id
```

It will give the same result as the previous query but with a value of timestamp for each record

I want this value to be the most recent timestamp could that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the max() function.

```
select forum.match_static_id, 
   count(forum.match_static_id) 'comment_no',
   max(forum.timestamp)
Group By forum.match_static_id
```

Here's a list and explanation of the available [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select forum.match_static_id, 
count(forum.match_static_id) 'comment_no',
max(forum.timestamp)
Group By forum.match_static_id
```